# Tensorflow in Python cryptic file gets read in

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use this example with my own dataset https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_customization/demo/text_classification.ipynb

The code is exactly the same except my `data_path` looks like this: `data_path = '/Users/developer/.keras/datasets/chat'`

If I just copy and paste the downloaded txt files to my corresponding folders, it works just fine, but once I create my own files or delete/modify copied ones, I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 27: invalid start byte`

All the files are UTF-8.

I figured `train_data` contains something weird. There is a text that contains `b'\x00\x00\x00\x01Bud1\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00\x10\x0c\`
It comes out of nowhere, because `train_data` size is always 1 more than the actual number of files in the folder and all the files seem to be ok.

Where might that cryptic thing be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is experiencing this problem on macOS, after 10 hours of debugging tensorflow code I found out it's .DS_Store file. It's not visible even when you set show hidden files for some reason. So remove the file.